# Python Flask Broadcast Message

Tags: python, flask-socketio

Using socketio in my flask app, I want to display the name of the sender and the message, but here the message only appears, and the sender's name only shows "[object object] hello" in the browser.

```
**# server.py

    from flask import Flask, render_template
    from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit

    app = Flask(__name__)

    app.config[ 'SECRET_KEY' ] = 'jsbcfsbfjefebw237u3gdbdc'
    socketio = SocketIO( app )

    @app.route( '/' ) 
    def hello():
        return render_template( './index.html' )

    def messageRecived():
        print( 'message was received!!!' )

    @socketio.on( 'my event' ) 
    def handle_my_custom_event( json ):   
        print( 'recived my event: ' + str( json ) )   
        socketio.emit( 'my response', json, callback=messageRecived )

    if __name__ == '__main__':   
        socketio.run( app, debug = True )
```

## index.html

**

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <b>Type your message below <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></span></b>
     <div class="clearfix" style="margin-top: 5px;"></div>
     <div id="username">My Name</div>
     <div style="padding-top: 5px;"></div>
     <input type="text" class="message form-control" placeholder="Messages">
     <div style="padding-top: 5px;"></div>
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span> Send</button>
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

---

**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.7.3/socket.io.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var socket = io.connect( 'http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port )
  // broadcast a message
    socket.on( 'connect', function() {
        socket.emit( 'my event', {
        data: 'User Connected'
    } )
    var form = $( 'form' ).on( 'submit', function( e ) {
        e.preventDefault()
        let username = $( '#username' ).val()
        let user_input = $( 'input.message' ).val()
        socket.emit( 'my event', {
            username : $("#username"),
            message : user_input
        } )
      // empty the input field
            $( 'input.message' ).val( '' ).focus()
        } )
    })
    socket.on( 'my response', function( msg ) {
    console.log( msg )
    if( typeof msg.username !== 'undefined' ) {
        $( 'h1' ).remove()
        $( 'div.message_holder' ).append( '<div class="msg_bbl"><b style="color: #000">'+msg.username+'</b> '+msg.message+'</div>' )
        }
    } )
</script>**
```

Comment: Please stop reverting edits, your original formatting is terrible. Format code blocks *as code blocks*, not quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending a DOM element to the server, instead of its contents. Add a `.text()` to get the actual user name:

```
    socket.emit( 'my event', {
        username : $("#username").text(),
        message : user_input
    } )
```